# Setting hl-line-mode for programming modes

Tags: init-file, highlighting, buffer-local, hl-line-mode

In my init file I have this:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))
```

So it shows line numbers only for programming modes. I tried to do the same with `hl-line-mode`, but it does not work:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-line-mode 1)))
```

Why is that? Both are buffer-local minor modes, according to the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: It does work for me.  Have you tried with emacs -Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an unrelated problem where a symbolic link was not set so the changes I made to the init file were not being loaded. Now it works.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so we can close this question.